# java casting an Object as a PrintWriter

Tags: java

I have an array of type `Object` in which I am saving object of different types, I want to cast them back their specific types after I take them out of the array. So when I take the PrintWriter object out I try `PrintWriter(objArray[1][2])`, but this does not work, how can I do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downcasting is to be done as follows:

```
SubType instanceOfSubType = (SubType) instanceOfSuperType;
```

Thus, in your particular case you probably want to do this:

```
PrintWriter printWriter = (PrintWriter) objArray[1][2];
```

Also see "Casting Objects" chapter in [Sun's tutorial about inheritance](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) (scroll about half down).

That said, collecting everything in an opaque `Object[]` is not really ideal. If you can, just create a custom Javabean-like class with under each an encapsulated `PrintWriter` field. E.g.

```
public class MyBean {
    private PrintWriter printWriter;
    public void setPrintWriter(PrintWriter printWriter) {
        this.printWriter = printWriter;
    }
    public PrintWriter getPrintWriter() {
        return printWriter;
    }
}
```

This way you can collect them in a `List<MyBean>` (to learn more about collections, check this [Sun tutorial on the subject](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html)).

```
List<MyBean> myBeans = new ArrayList<MyBean>();
MyBean myBean1 = new MyBean();
myBean1.setPrintWriter(printWriter1);
myBeans.add(myBean1);
MyBean myBean2 = new MyBean();
myBean2.setPrintWriter(printWriter2);
myBeans.add(myBean2);
// ...
```

so that you can retrieve them as follows:

```
for (MyBean myBean : myBeans) {
    PrintWriter printWriter = myBean.getPrintWriter();
    // ...
}
```